# How to restore sql 2000 database backup in sql 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000

I am trying to restore backup of a database which was created in SQL 2000 in SQL 2005 and getting this error

> Index was outside the bounds of the
>   array.(Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.Smo)

How can I restore ?

Comment: Have you tried executing a T-SQL RESTORE command directly?

Comment: @DanGuzman I have no idea about that command .. Please let me  know ..

Answer (score 1):

Try executing a T-SQL `RESTORE` command.  This can be scripted from the SSMS Restore Database dialog or you can use the script examples below.

To restore a database to the same file locations as the original database files, run this command from an SSMS query window, substituting you backup file path:

```
RESTORE DATABASE YourDatabaseName
FROM DISK='C:\Backups\YourDatabaseName.bak'
WITH STATS = 10;
```

If the file locations on the target server differ, specify the MOVE option with the logical file names and new file paths:

```
RESTORE DATABASE YourDatabaseName
FROM DISK='C:\Backups\YourDatabaseName.bak'
WITH
      MOVE 'YourDatabaseName' TO 'D:\DataFiles\YourDatabaseName.mdf'
    , MOVE 'YourDatabaseName_Log' TO 'L:\DataFiles\YourDatabaseName_Log.ldf'
    , STATS = 10;
```

The logical file names needed for the above command can be obtained using `RESTORE FILELISTONLY`:

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY
FROM DISK='C:\Backups\YourDatabaseName.bak';
```

Be sure to update stats for all tables after the restore.  This can be done with sp_updatestats:

```
EXEC sp_updatestats;
```